# Why Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 showing no Error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I wrote a code in Visual Studio 2012 :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char name1[20], name2[20];
    name1 = "John";
    strcpy(name2, name1);
    cout << name2 << endl;
}
```

I know strcpy requires a library `<cstring>` . 
Codeblocks gives an error : 'strcpy' is not declared. But Visual studio doesn't give any error and compile and runs just fine.

Why? This is a big problem for me because I just started ACM problem solving.

Comment: `name1 = "John";`  shouldn't compile, you can't assign to arrays, does VS2012 really allow this? As for `strcpy` perhaps VSs implementation of `<iostream>` includes `<cstring>` at some point.

Comment: Compilation does indeed fail due to `name1 = "John"`

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` should be your default choice for strings, not char arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string name1, name2;
    name1 = "John";
    name2 = name1;
    cout << name2 << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the VC++ headers, `<cstring>` is included via `<iostream>`, which you have included. The chain is:

```
<iostream>
 <istream>
  <ostream>
   <ios>
    <xlocnum>
     <streambuf>
      <xiosbase>
       <xlocale>
        <cstring>
```